# Phonegap Don's BluetoothSerial plugin: send and print text to a bluetooth printer

Tags: android, cordova, printing, bluetooth

Working on an Android/Phonegap (built with [adobe phonegap builder](https://build.phonegap.com)) project to print some strings to a Bluetooth printer.

I'm using last version of Phonegap and [Don's BluetoothSerial plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/tree/ef6d7e0ab4a44375c32892192f3f668f57681b49).

I have two issues:

1. I can send a string using *bluetoothSerial.write*, it says that it's a
   success but nothing happens on my printer (I tried to put some "\n" but it was useless)
2. *bluetoothSerial.connect* and *bluetoothSerial.connectInsecure* are both going to failure

I tried my best to check existing code on the web but didn't found out something about this. I'm totally lost and don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing something.

Please see below my very basic code:

**HTML**:

```
<button id="testco" type="button">Test Connect</button>
<button id="listnwrite" type="button">List & Write</button>
<button id="insecure" type="button">Insecure connect</button>
<button id="deco" type="button">Disconnect bluetooth</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#testco").click(function() {
        bluetoothSerial.connect("00:19:5D:23:D1:7F", connectSuccess, connectFailure);
    });

    $("#listnwrite").click(function() {
        bluetoothSerial.list(function(devices) {
            devices.forEach(function(device) {
                var data = "something \n";
                alert(device.address);
                bluetoothSerial.connect(device.address, connectSuccess, connectFailure);
                bluetoothSerial.write(data, success, failure);
            })
        }, connectFailure);
    });

    $("#insecure").click(function() {
        bluetoothSerial.connectInsecure("00:19:5D:23:D1:7F", connectSuccess, connectFailure);
    });

    $("#deco").click(function() {
        bluetoothSerial.disconnect(sucessdeco, faildeco);
    });

});
```

All failure/success functions are sending some alert('[ko/ok]') to check status.

Is anyone could help me on this? Is there some special chars I need to send to my Bluetooth printer to have a print?

Comment: I don't see that plugin on the approved PhoneGap Build plugin list: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins. On PGBuild, you can only use plugins listed on that page.

Comment: It's approved, please see this link: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check this plugin is not made to be used with bluetooth printer. I'm now using a plugin mapped to my BT printer SDK and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Do you could tell how did you print using BT printer? 

grateful

Answer (score 1):

To run your code with a Bluetooth printer, you need that your printer supports the ESC / POS protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESC/P) and be configured to receive.

Then you have to finish your string with "\ r \ n".

```
 $("#listnwrite").click(function() {
        bluetoothSerial.list(function(devices) {
            devices.forEach(function(device) {
                var data = "something \r\n";
                alert(device.address);
                bluetoothSerial.connect(device.address, connectSuccess, connectFailure);
                bluetoothSerial.write(data, success, failure);
            })
        }, connectFailure);
 });
```

For my case, I use a Bluetooth receipt printer "Star" model: TSP650II
To enter the "ESC / POS" mode, it took place the DIP switch 1 (on the printer) to off.